# How to make a menu item bold when it has been selected?

Tags: css, menu, navigation, onclick

I am trying to figure out what the best way would be to make a navigation/menu link bold when that link has been opened.

Would a .click CSS altering function be the best way?

Comment: Add a class dynamically and set the `font-weight` in it.

Comment: `a:visited{font-weight: bold}`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "opened"? If you mean that a link is visited try:

```
a:visited {font-weight:bold;}
```

Other selector for a states could be:

```
a:link    {font-weight:bold;} /*normal state*/
a:visited {font-weight:bold;} /*for already visited links*/
a:hover   {font-weight:bold;} /*mouseover*/
a:active  {font-weight:bold;} /*click on item*/
```

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned it depends on whether the need is to make prior visited links (or) the link of the current page (like in a selected menu item) as bold.

Comment: The site can be viewed here http://staging.oneforall.com.au/core-new/index.html# 
However the Selected menu link only flashes bold for a split second, how do I make it remain bold until it is hidden or a new link is selected?

Comment: Try with `a:focus`.
[focus selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)

Comment: :focus didnt do anything